May object pointer be always compared with nullptr in a constant expression?
The following program was reduced to demonstrate the question. struct A has a constexpr member function that compares this against some pointer, which can be nullptr. Then this member function is called for a temporary object (taking address of rvalue) inside a constant expression:
struct A {
    A * a = nullptr; // in real program this pointer can be changed
    constexpr bool f() {
        return a != this;
    }
};

static_assert( A{}.f() );

Clang and MSVC are ok with it, but GCC does not like this code, complaining:
<source>:8:21: error: non-constant condition for static assertion
    8 | static_assert( A{}.f() );
      |                ~~~~~^~
<source>:4:18: error: '((&<anonymous>) != 0)' is not a constant expression
    4 |         return a != this;

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/evK1Y1r8e
Is it a well formed program? Or is it always necessary to check that pointers are not nullptr before comparison in a constant expression?

in real program this pointer can be changed suggests that the comparison may not be const enough for compile time. Under what circumstances can a's value be changed? Are they all compile time-only?

No it is not. A* a can be changed at runtime, so it is not a constant expression and thus you cannot use it in a constexpr function. If A* could be calculated at compile time then it would have been static constexpe A* a = ...

@PepijnKramer The specific A object that's considered here is a temporary that exists only during the evaluation of the static_assert operand. It can't have its a member be changed at run time. So there is no problem with that.

@user4581301 See above.

@user17732522 Considered here, yes. I'm concerned about the real-world case. Does the example shown here oversimplify and no longer represent the true problem?

This is just a GCC bug: of course the (symbolic) address of a temporary constructed during constant evaluation is known to that evaluation.
